# bandwidth in splunk Enterprise

Tags: splunk, bandwidth

I want to calculate the bandwidth beetwen a sender and a reciver in real time using Splunk Enterprise.

I would really really appreciate some help with this. I have searched previous questions, but can't seem to find the answer.

Kind Regards

Answer (score 1):

You can look at the metrics events, which are internal to splunk. Details are found at https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/8.0.4/Troubleshooting/Aboutmetricslog

Your search would look something like the following. Read the docs and see what fields are relevant to you.

```
index=_interal source=*metrics.log group=tcpout_connections | stats avg(_tcp_Bps) by host
```

Note that the metrics are written every 30 seconds, which is close to realtime, but not quite.